# How to declare an array of objects for a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, object, for-loop

I want to insert the details of a quiz in which among a lot of strings (question, professor, course, etc) , I have one array of answers (and its corresponding array of is_correct), so I thought of creating a for loop to insert each answer properly.

The problem is I don't know how to correctly call the questionQuiz object. I noticed if I declare two different objects at the beginning and then do this manually:

```
$questionQuiz1 -> insert_question($quiz_name,$professor,$course,$question,$points,$answer[0],$is_correct[0]);
$questionQuiz2-> insert_question($quiz_name,$professor,$course,$question,$points,$answer[1],$is_correct[1]);
```

it works. 
How should I declare this object as an array and use it in an iteration?

I tried something like this but it isn't correct.

```
$questionQuiz[]  = new Test();
    if(isset($_POST['quiz_name'],$_POST['professor'],$_POST['course'],$_POST['question'],$_POST['points'],$_POST['answer'], $_POST['is_correct'])) {
        $quiz_name = $_POST['quiz_name'];
        $professor = $_POST['professor'];
        $course = $_POST['course']; 
        $question = $_POST['question'];
        $points = $_POST['points']; 
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        $is_correct = $_POST['is_correct'];


        if(!empty($quiz_name) && !empty($professor)&& !empty($course)&& !empty($question)&& !empty($points)&& !empty($answer) && !empty($is_correct)){


            for($i=0; $i<count($answer); $i++) {
                $questionQuiz[$i] -> insert_question($quiz_name,$professor,$course,$question,$points,$answer[$i],$is_correct[$i]);
            }


        }else{
            echo json_encode("param must not be empty"); 
        }
    }
```

Should I instantiate $questionQuiz[]  = new Test(); inside the loop? I tested and it seems to work, is it correct to do it this way?

Comment: what the error you get

Comment: it only inserts the first $i it gets

Comment: should I create a new object inside the for loop?

Comment: @krystal By doing just that.  Don't create the object outside of the loop, create it _inside_.  What you create _outside_ of the loop should be an array.  Then assign the new object (within the loop) to a new element in the array each time through the loop, and call the function on that new element.

Comment: Inside loop. Instance of test is only available when $i=0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem in your code, is that you only create 1 instance of `Test` class (at the top). And inside your `for` loop, you only reference it and call the `insert_question` method on it. Beware: in this case only `$questionQuiz[0]` exists, so in the other cases nothing happens (or an error might occur).

**Option 1**

If you only want to call the method on the `Test` class, you could call it in your `for` loop like this:

```
(new Test())->insert_question( ... etc ... );
```

**Option 2**

If you want to store the created class objects, you create a new `Test` object, call the `insert_question` method on it and add the object to your array:

```
$object = new Test();
$object->insert_question( ... etc ...);
$questionQuiz[] = $object;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the logic all laid out, your just not doing what you're saying.

Create an array, and then add a new object to that array each time through the loop.

```
$questionQuiz[]  = array();
    if(isset($_POST['quiz_name'],$_POST['professor'],$_POST['course'],$_POST['question'],$_POST['points'],$_POST['answer'], $_POST['is_correct'])) {

...

for($i=0; $i<count($answer); $i++) {
    $questionQuiz[$i] = new Test();
    $questionQuiz[$i] -> insert_question($quiz_name,$professor,$course,$question,$points,$answer[$i],$is_correct[$i]);
            }

...
```

I will note however, that something seems off about having a function called `insert_question()` where you individually insert single answers options on seemingly multiple-choice questions.  I would think you would pass an array of answer options with corresponding correctness.

Comment: The logic inside the function is this: if the question already exists in the table, add its options in the answers table. If not, perform the first insertion of the question too before adding the corresponding answers. I thought of it this way because the user (a professor) can add as many answers as he wants for a question when he creates a quiz. When he presses the "add question" (with its answers) button, I call this script to perform the insertion. Is it not ok? Should I do 2 different scripts?

Comment: @krystal So I'm not sure that you need `$questionQuiz` to be an array at all.  Can't you just declare `$questionQuiz = new Test();` and then within the loop do `$questionQuiz->insert_question(...);`?  I think you've overcomplicated this.

Comment: Well I did this at first but it only inserted in the first iteration and then didn't insert anything else

Comment: It works only if I declare the object inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned storing the posts to an object array. would something like this work?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['quiz_name'], $_POST['professor'], $_POST['course'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['points'], $_POST['answer'], $_POST['is_correct']))
{
    $quiz_name = $_POST['quiz_name'];
    $professor = $_POST['professor'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $points = $_POST['points'];
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $is_correct = $_POST['is_correct'];
}

if(!empty($answer_array) && count($answer_array[5]) > 0)
{
    $count = count($answer_array[5]);
    $questionQuiz[]  = new Test();
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        //assuming your class is correct and you'll need to have it handle the incoming array how you want it to
        $answer_array = array($quiz_name, $professor, $course, $question, $points, $answer[$i], $is_correct[$i]);
        $questionQuiz[$i] -> insert_question($answer_array);
    }

}
else
{
    echo "param must not be empty";
}
?>
```